# DataSource null and binding in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a GUI written code, and have some listbox.

```
$selectedDBTablesToAdd = $lbDbTables.SelectedItems
$list = $lbDbTableInApp.DataSource + $selectedDBTablesToAdd | Sort-Object -Property name -Descending

$lbDbTableInApp.DataSource = $list
```

And it works.
However, I need to clear data before this lines like:

```
$lbDbTableInApp.DataSource = $null
```

And it removes all items from a listbox.
But, now, with this line of code, I am getting an erorr like:
`"DataSource": "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource."`

**Approach:**
I trierd to introduce a new object binding like:

```
 $bindingSource = new-object System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
 #and then recconect my DataSpurce for $lbDbTableInApp=>
 $bindingSource.DataSource = $list
 $lbDbTableInApp.DataSource = $bindingSource.DataSource
```

But still same error appears.

**Constraints:**
Going for Items instead of a DataSource is not an option.

I am using Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` this class should have method `Clear()` to empty it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2